# How to avoid "Dropping 'draws_df' class as required metadata was removed" warning?

Tags: r, stan

When doing certain operations on a `draws_df` data frame the class gets dropped leading to a warning; see example below.  How can that warning be avoided? (What I have in mind is either a function/parameter in `posterior`, or perhaps a better way of doing what my example does without using `pivot_longer`.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(posterior)

example_draws() |> 
  as_draws_df() |> 
  pivot_longer(!.draw) |> 
  filter(str_starts(name, 'theta')) |> 
  mutate(cumulative = cumsum(value), .by = .draw)
# Warning message:
# Dropping 'draws_df' class as required metadata was removed.
```